# Why for a real number $x$ and an even integer $n, x^{1/n}$ is not real if $x<0$?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, arithmetic, real-numbers, exponentiation

Why for a real number $x$ and an even integer $n$, $\;x^{1/n}$ is not real if $x<0$?
What I'm really asking is how do you define a complex number without referring to imaginary numbers.

How do you define a complex number without circular logic that involves a complex number
($a+bi$ where $i$ is the imaginary unit, and $a, b$ are real).

Explain without assuming I'm defining functions.

Comment: Is $x\ge 0$? (Otherwise what happens if $x=-1$ and $n=2$ for example?)

Comment: $x^{\frac{1}{n}} = \sqrt[n]{x}$, if $x$ is negative and $n$ is even, you cannot have a real negative square root

Comment: $i$ is the imaginary unit; it's like saying to define $10$ without using any real numbers. However, there are some specific ways to define some complex numbers, e.g. the roots of unity, but almost all complex numbers must be defined using the imaginary unit.

Comment: "how do you define a complex number without referring to imaginary numbers?" the answer is that you need to refer to imaginary numbers to define complex numbers. Why is $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ not real under those conditions? and without referring to imaginary numbers? suppose it is real, then you get a contradiction, this suggest that there are operation in the reals that don't give you back a real number, and you need a bigger family of numbers. It's like asking: what's $3\div 2$ in the integers?, we don't know, that's why we need rationals etc.

Comment: Are you familiar with the theorem saying every real polynomial can be factored as a product of linear polynomials and quadratic polynomials with negative discriminant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x<0$,$n=2k$

Assume $x^{\frac{1}{2k}}$ to be a real number

What this means that there exist a Real number $p=x^{\frac{1}{2k}}$ such that $p^{2k}=x$

But $p^{2k}=(p^k)^2$, and The square of any real number is always non-negative, Hence $(p^k)^2$ is also non-negative, which in fact means $p^{2k}$ is non-negative

But $p^{2k}=x$, Which follows x must be non-negative, Which contradicts the assumption that There exist a real number $x^{\frac{1}{2k}}$,Such that $x<0$

Hence our assumption is wrong, There does not exist a a real number $x^{\frac{1}{2k}}$,Such that $x<0$

Now $p$ is not real

That means there is a whole set of such cases where all such $p's$ are not real

Now Imaginary numbers were named as such numbers, Whose $2^{nd}$ or $4^{th}$ or even powers would lead to a negative real number, Historically, They were first
conceived by Italian Mathematician Gerolamo Cardano, While solving a general cubic equation

Roots such as $a+b\sqrt-1$ Were expressed, Now, These itself had no real meaning in those times, But when these roots were put into the polynomial, The result would give out "$0$",Meaning they had mathematical usefulness, Such complete expressions were later named complex numbers, But the imaginary parts were indeed already used before, For a short history lesson, [This](https://www.math.uri.edu/%7Emerino/spring06/mth562/ShortHistoryComplexNumbers2006.pdf) might be useful, Note that $i$,whose notation as $\sqrt-1$ was given by Rafael Bombelli, always was used historically for its mathematical usefulness as a number whose square is $-1$

It was later in time that geometrical interpretations were given to such expressions and later called complex numbers as $a+ib$, Note $i$ as complex number $0+1i$ was later seen as "complex", after these definitions were rigorously defined, Hence, historically complex numbers were consequence of Applying mathematical operations on imaginary and Real numbers

Answer (score 0):

"How do you define a complex number without circular logic that involves a complex number is $a+bi$ where $i$ is a complex number, $a$ real $b$ real."

First, you write ${\bf R}[x]$ for the *ring* of all polynomials with real coefficients.

Then you let $J$ be the *ideal* of all multiples of the polynomial $x^2+1$.

Given a polynomial $p(x)$ in ${\bf R}[x]$, you define the *coset* of $J$ containing $p(x)$ to be the set of all polynomials of the form $p(x)+j(x)$ where $j(x)$ runs through $J$, that is, it's the set of all polynomials that are $p(x)$ plus a multiple of $x^2+1$. We'll use the notation $\overline{p(x)}$ for this coset.

Notice that any polynomial $p(x)$, when you divide by $x^2+1$, gives you a quotient and a remainder, and the remainder is a polynomial of degree one, $ax+b$ for some real numbers $a,b$. You have
$$
p(x)=(x^2+1)q(x)+ax+b
$$
($q(x)$ is the quotient when you do the division). Notice that in this situation, $\overline{p(x)}=\overline{ax+b}$; since $p(x)$ and $ax+b$ differ by a multiple of $x^2+1$, they define the same coset of $J$.

So, the set $\bf C$ of all cosets of $J$ is the set of all $\overline{ax+b}$ with $a,b$ real.

Well, $\bf C$ is the complex numbers, defined here with no circularity. The element $\overline x$ satisfies $\overline{x}^2=\overline{-1}$ because $\overline{x^2+1}=\overline0$. So $\overline x$ plays the rôle of $i$.